# How can I get WordPress plugin version number on the theme?

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, wordpress-theming, theme-development

I want to get a specific plugin version number on my theme area. For example, I want to show the currently active WooCommerce plugin version number. How can I get it?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need something like this

```
$plugin_dir = WP_PLUGIN_DIR . '/woocommerce/woocommerce.php';

$plugin_data = get_plugin_data($plugin_dir);

echo $plugin_data['Version'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's working. But the array 'version' word would be capital word 'Version'. Otherwise, it's showing Notice: Undefined index.

$plugin_dir = WP_PLUGIN_DIR . '/woocommerce/woocommerce.php';

$plugin_data = get_plugin_data($plugin_dir);

echo $plugin_data['Version'];